# Tools to view/edit user space memory of running processes?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memory, operating-systems

Are there any tools to view/edit user space memory of running processes on Linux?

It would be a great learning tool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The memory of a process is available as the file `/proc/12345/mem` where 12345 is the process ID. You won't be able to learn anything directly from it for a while yet, though. The first thing to figure out is which parts are mapped; this information is available in `/proc/12345/maps` and `/proc/12345/smaps`. Entries in `/proc` are documented in the kernel documentation at [`Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt). The `lsof` command will give information about files that the process has mapped into memory in a more readable way.

It may be more instructive to look at the running process with a debugger. The usual debugger under Linux is [Gdb](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/). Gdb has a simple command line interface; [DDD](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/) and [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) provide user-friendlier interfaces. For best results, look at a program that still has debugging symbols and whose source is available (i.e. look at a program you just compiled with `-g` and haven't stripped).

You should also know about `strace` to watch the system calls a process is making, and `ltrace` to watch (some) library calls.